# can't call anonymously function again in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var func = (function(){
//do something
})();
```

and then I call `func()` it says func is not a function?

if that's the case I have to do this

```
function func(){
//do something
};
func();
```

and later

```
func();
```

correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> var func = (function(){
> //do something
> })();
> ```

This code has `()` at the end, i.e. it's already calling the function. The value assigned to `func` is the return value of the function.

If you want to assign the function itself to `func`, just do:

```
var func = function () {
  //do something
};
```

Comment: I want it to be init by itself and call it again, not possible?

Comment: @AliciaBrandon What do you mean by "init by itself and call it again"?

Comment: call by itself I mean

Comment: Just add `func();` if you want to call it right there. Or, if you're crazy, `var func; (func = function () { ... })();`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct; `func` is the result of *calling* your function (caused by the `()` after the definition).  Leaving that off would fix this.

Note that you cannot re-use an anonymous function, since you can't identify the function to be re-used.  Since you are assigning it to a variable, you are effectively naming it.

Answer (score 1):

Function you use here is already executed to variable `func` with `(function(){})()`

to use `func` as function you have to return function

```
var func = (function(){
  return function (){ 
     //  do something here
  }
})();
```

so you can call `func()`

jsfiddle 
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/uve2343c/)

Comment: This seems more elaborate than other answers without any difference in behavior.

Comment: Thank you, Thought will add more for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

A **Self-Invoking Anonymous Function** is a function that you can execute only one time because it has no **reference**.

In this case

```
var func = (function(){
    //do something
})();
```

the variable func has no reference to the anonymous function, then it will contain the value returned by the function, in this case undefined.

If you want to be able to call the function you have to create a reference like this:

```
var func = function(){
    //do something
};
```

or

```
function func() { 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make like this you don't need () <- this in last line

```
 var func = function(){

    }
console.log(func);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax

```js
(function(){
  // Do something
})()
```

Is called [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

When you do

```js
var func = (function(){
//do something
})();
```

You not assigning a function but its response to it. So if you return an object, it will have reference of that object and not the function.

If you wish to have a function to act as an init and being able to call it after words, have a named function and call this function,

```js
function init(){}
init();
```

Refer [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) for more reference.

Also when you define a function like

```js
function  func1(){}
// or
var func1 = function(){}
```

an reference is created in memory and is assigned to functionName, and later this name is used to call it. When you create an anonymous function, you are not storing any reference and hence you cannot call it.